# Where are Jboss drools projects stored?

Tags: drools

I am using kie-drools-wb-6.5.0.Final-eap6_4.war to create a project and generate a DRL file. 
But am not able to find the physical location of any file created using the Drools workbench.
Where can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're in the `.niogit` directory.